# What's the role of "for" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrases

> Denis's drug war thriller, starring Emily Blunt, shot up to third with
>   $12.1 million **for** the **acclaimed** Lionsgate release.

What's the role or function of "for" and what does "acclaimed" modify in this sentence?

Does it mean it made a good result because it was released by the Lionsgate which is acclaimed for good movies? Does it mean the Lionsgate was acclaimed or the movie released was acclaimed?

Comment: "the acclaimed Lionsgate release" earned $12.1 million.

Comment: And 'acclaimed' modifies 'release'.

Comment: I think Dennis's should be Dennis', without the last S.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's make sure we're on the same page regarding the beginning of the sentence:

"Denis's drug war thriller" -- noun phrase at the beginning of the sentence.  Probably a subject.

"starring Emily Blunt" -- nonrestrictive participial phrase, modifies "Denis's drug war thriller".  Since the commas mark it as nonrestrictive, we can assume that Denis has only one drug war thriller.

"shot" -- verb.  This  agrees with the initial noun phrase and confirms that that noun phrase is a subject.

"up" -- preposition.  We expect the prepositional phrase to modify the verb "shot".  "Shot up" might be a phrasal verb, if "up" is intransitive.

"to third" -- prepositional phrase.  The preposition "up" must be intransitive, since a prepositional phrase does not act as the object of another prepositional phrase.  We expect this phrase to modify the verb.

"with $12.1 million" -- prepositional phrase, modifies the verb.

If we agree on this much of the parsing, the rest should be fairly straightforward.

"for" -- preposition.  In this position, a prepositional phrase might modify "$12.1 million" or it might modify "shot (up)".  We should assume that it modifies the closed available construction until and unless we have reason to believe that it doesn't.

"the" -- the definite article.  It should modify something that follows it.

"acclaimed" -- participle.  This participle is not part of a verb phrase, so it must modify something.  It does not modify any word in front of it, so it must modify something behind it.

"Lionsgate" -- proper name, used as an attribute.  We might at first assume that this is the object of the preposition "for".  However, the following word will make us re-evaluate our assumption.  As it turns out, it modifies "release".

"release" -- noun, simple object of "for".  There is no other role for this word to play.  Since this has to be the simple prepositional object, "Lionsgate" must modify this.

Now we can see how these words form coherent phrases:

"Release" is a countable singular noun, so it will require a determiner.  "Lionsgate" is a modifier, but not a determiner, so "Lionsgate release" isn't coherent, but "a Lionsgate release" and "the Lionsgate release" are.  Still, "Lionsgate" modifies "release", and the two words can act together as a unit.

"Acclaimed" is a modifier.  It modifies "Lionsgate release".  It does not modify "Lionsgate" by itself.  We're talking about a release which is both an acclaimed release and a Lionsgate release.

"The" is the definite article.  It modifies the complete phrase that follows it.  The definite article is definitely a determiner, and "the" satisfies the requirement that "release" have a determiner.  We now have a complete and coherent noun phrase: "the acclaimed Lionsgate release".

"For" is a preposition.  The object of this preposition is the coherent noun phrase "the acclaimed Lionsgate release".  The prepositional phrase "for the acclaimed Lionsgate release" must modify something.

The closest possibility, of course, is "$12.1 million".  This seems to be a sensible possibility.  "12.1 million dollars for the acclaimed Lionsgate release" is a coherent noun phrase.

We can examine the possibility that the prepositional phrase in question modifies the verb of the clause.  Prepositional phrases are adjuncts.  We should be able to remove them without changing the grammar of the remaining structure.  If we assume that "for the acclaimed Lionsgate release" does *not* modify "dollars", then we should be able to remove "with $12.1 million" and "to third".

We can't.  Consider the result:  "Denis's drug war thriller, starring Emily Blunt, shot up for the acclaimed Lionsgate release".  This is not a coherent sentence.  The thriller shot up for its own release?  I can't make sense of that idea in this context.

The phrasing "shot up for its own release" might make sense in a different context.  In this context, "with money for its own release" is the far more sensible option.

Denis made a movie.  This movie was a thriller about a drug war.  The movie starred Emily Blunt.  The movie shot up to third, which probably means that it shot up to third place on some specific list.  The movie shot up with $12.1 million.  Without more context we don't know whether those dollars are net profits or box office receipts or some other metric, but we know that these dollars are the means by which the movie shot up.  The dollars have a source or a reason for existing.  This source is the movie's release.  The release came from Lionsgate.  The release was acclaimed.

It is quite likely that box office receipts were that good because the release was acclaimed.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the role of **for**?

There is a weird shift in the second part of this sentence.

> Denis's drug war thriller...shot up to third [place] ...
>
> ... with $12.1 million [in box-office receipts] for the acclaimed
>   Lionsgate release.

The second part of the sentence, the *with*-phrase, is not integrated. It augments, and yet the "for phrase" is an attempted integration.

Consider:

**In the Central Division, the Chicago Cubs are in the basement, with zero wins and five losses.**

**In the Central Division, the Chicago Cubs are in the basement, with zero wins and five losses *for this perennial losing team.***